# How to re-position CDK Overlay once it opened on changing of overlay-origin element

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm trying to make a multi-select dropdown component using angular material CDK overlay. As in the code below (taken from angular material select component)

```
<div class="multi-select-dd">
    <label class="multi-select-dd-text">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="multi-select-dd-text-container">
        <ul class="taggle_list"
            cdk-overlay-origin
            (click)="toggle()"
            #origin="cdkOverlayOrigin"
            #trigger>
            <li>
                <input type="text"
                       class="taggle_input"
                       tabindex="1"
                       style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"
                       autocomplete="off">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<ng-template cdk-connected-overlay
             cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop
             cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass="cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop"
             [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="origin"
             [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="panelOpen"
             [cdkConnectedOverlayPositions]="_positions"
             [cdkConnectedOverlayMinWidth]="_triggerRect?.width"
             [cdkConnectedOverlayOffsetY]="_offsetY"
             (backdropClick)="close()"
             (attach)="_onAttached()"
             (detach)="close()">
    <div style="background-color: lightgreen;">
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

So whenever an item is selected from dropdown, It'll be shown as a chip in the box which is the connected position. which will change the height of origin element.

**Question:** Is there any standard way in the overlay to reposition it startY position on  overlay-origin height change?

Comment: Did you even find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes.. by using some nested hidden api of overlay. UpdatePostion. Will post the exact code on Monday as i don't have my laptop with me now

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and I found this way to update the position after it has been opened.

```
@ViewChild(CdkConnectedOverlay) cdkConnectedOverlay: CdkConnectedOverlay;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
       // this is triggered when its opened for the first time and each time you modify the position
       // posChange is an Object ConnectedOverlayPositionChange that contains
       // connectionPair: with originX/Y,Overlay X/Y and offsetsX/Y
       // scrollableViewProperties
        this.cdkConnectedOverlay.positionChange.pipe(first()).subscribe(posChange => {
            // change any properties that you need about the connectedOverlay
            this.cdkConnectedOverlay.offsetY = 0;
            // this will trigger again positionChange thats why we only take the first
            this.cdkConnectedOverlay.overlayRef.updatePosition();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier way.

```js
     // data you want to show is contained in the matDialogConfig
     let mc = this.getConfig(data);
     // Tell Matdialog which Angular component to use.
     let mdRef = this.md.open(MessageComponent, mc);
```

Grab the data out of MessageComponent

```js
    import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material/dialog";
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Inject } from "@angular/core";
    import { inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
    
    @Component({
      selector: "lib-message",
      templateUrl: "./message.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./message.component.css"],
    })
    export class MessageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
        // get the injected dialog data
        this.data = data;
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
      ngAfterViewInit() {}
    }
```

In HTML, this is only markup needed.

```html
    {{data}}
```

The CSS in the MessageComponent allows full control on position.

```css
    :host {
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10em;
        left: 20em;
        height: 10em;
        width: 20em;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
    }
```

Your message component takes precedence over the CDK Overlay! Very nice.